# Сохранить загруженные картинки в php.(FILEUPLOAD)

Tags: php, upload, multiple

Здравствуйте форумчане..Нужно было сделать простенькую админку в php.Знания у меня по php 
так себе.Возникла проблема с сохранением картинки в директорию,откуда потом буду их брать для отображения на странице. Проблема в том что я хочу сохранить разом несколько картинок.
Отсюда и проблемы метод move_uploaded_file(); возвращает false.Собсна..вот код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- форма загрузки -->
    <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">

      <input type="file" name="userfile[]" multiple="multiple"/>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="отпрaвить"/>
    </form>   

<?php
function reArrayFiles(&$file_post) {

    $file_ary = array();
    $file_count = count($file_post['name']);
    $file_keys = array_keys($file_post);

    for ($i=0; $i<$file_count; $i++) {
        foreach ($file_keys as $key) {
            $file_ary[$i][$key] = $file_post[$key][$i];
        }
    }

    return $file_ary;
}

if ($_FILES['userfile']) {
    $file_ary = reArrayFiles($_FILES['userfile']);

    foreach ($file_ary as $file) {
        print 'File Name     :    ' . $file['name'];
           print '<br>';
        print 'File Type     :    ' . $file['type'];
           print '<br>';
        print 'File Size     :    ' . $file['size'];
           print '<hr>';
/*==========ВОТ ТУТ НУЖНО СОХРАНИТЬ ФАЙЛЫ В КАКУЮ НИБУДЬ ДИРЕКТОРИЮ==========*/
}
}


?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `foreach($_FILES as $file) {...`

Comment: @E_p метод reArrayFiles вообще не использовать?

Comment: Это не мне решать. Делайте как вам удобнее.

Comment: @E_p вы не подскажите каким должен быть второй параметр к методу move_uploaded_file() ? можно ли вот так                           
 $path= 'C:\\ ulpoadsimg\\';                
     move_uploaded_file(file['name',$path) ?

Comment: По идее пойдет. На php.net очень хорошая документация. Есть и на русском.